# How to show initial value other than zero on tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

When the code is executed, the default values are shown 0.0 for both the boxes. I want to change it to 50 & 60 respectively or any other numbers. How can this be done?

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

window = tk.Tk()

ws = window.winfo_screenwidth()
hs = window.winfo_screenheight()
w = 700 # width for the Tk root
h = 585  # height for the Tk root
x = (ws / 2) - (w / 2)
y = (hs / 2) - (h / 2)

window.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))   

canvas = tk.Canvas(window,bg="white",width=700, height=585, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()


l2 = tk.Label(canvas, text="Circumference of Tank", font="Calibri 12", bg="white")
canvas.create_window(15,78, window=l2, anchor=tk.NW)


PL1 = tk.DoubleVar()
entry_PL1 = ttk.Entry(canvas, textvariable=PL1)
entry_PL1.config({"background": "gainsboro"})
canvas.create_window(250,90, window=entry_PL1)


l3 = tk.Label(canvas, text="Height of Tank", font="Calibri 12", bg="white")
canvas.create_window(370,78, window=l3, anchor=tk.NW)

PH1 = tk.DoubleVar()
entry_PH1 = ttk.Entry(canvas, textvariable=PH1)
entry_PH1.config({"background": "gainsboro"})
canvas.create_window(610,90, window=entry_PH1)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just pass `value=...` when creating the `DoubleVar()` instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initial them like this:

```
PL1.set(50)
PH1.set(60)
```

And, add them before `window.mainloop()`